# Php scoping questions in reference to singletons, globals, wordpress, and wordpress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, singleton, global

I'm having trouble getting the wordpress json-api update post api call to work. I'm current on wordpress 3.8.1, json-api 1.1.1, and json-api-auth 1.7. I'm using the wordpress json-api-auth plugin to return a nonce and a cookie for update_post api call. After that, I use a call to the update_post endpoint to update a certain post that already exists. Using the error_log cmd, I have found that the issue lies in this block of code:

```
wp-includes/query.php (in the get_posts method)
2971                 // Check post status to determine if post should be displayed.
2972                 if ( !empty($this->posts) && ($this->is_single || $this->is_page) ) {
2973                         $status = get_post_status($this->posts[0]);
2974                         $post_status_obj = get_post_status_object($status);
2975                         //$type = get_post_type($this->posts[0]);
2976                         if ( !$post_status_obj->public ) {
2977                                 if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
2978                                         // User must be logged in to view unpublished posts.
2979                                         $this->posts = array();
2980                                 } else {
2981                                         if  ( $post_status_obj->protected ) {
2982                                                 // User must have edit permissions on the draft to preview.
2983                                                 if ( ! current_user_can($edit_cap, $this->posts[0]->ID) ) {
2984                                                         $this->posts = array();
2985                                                 } else {
2986                                                         $this->is_preview = true;
2987                                                         if ( 'future' != $status )
2988                                                                 $this->posts[0]->post_date = current_time('mysql');
2989                                                 }
2990                                         } elseif ( $post_status_obj->private ) {
2991                                                 if ( ! current_user_can($read_cap, $this->posts[0]->ID) )
2992                                                         $this->posts = array();
2993                                         } else {
2994                                                 $this->posts = array();
2995                                         }
2996                                 }
2997                         }
```

The call to is_user_logged_in() is returning false because the $current_user == 0, but I am logged in according to the api. I have tried to create a json_user global variable in generate_auth_cookie (wp-content/plugins/json-api-auth/controllers/Auth.php) and set it to the current_user variable in the set_posts_query function (wp-content/plugins/json-api/singletons/introspector.php) before calling the query_posts function in the wp-includes/query.php. The error_log returns $current_user->ID is still zero after $current_user = $json_user. I'm sure that there is something I'm missing and my workaround idea could be terrible. How do I change the $current_user object to something other than 0?

Comment: Update your version of WordPress.  Why are you developing against 3.8 when it's at 4.4?

Comment: That is the first thing I though of. But I work for a government institution and a change like that would involve 2 to 3 months of paperwork. Also, I would need the agreement of my fellow developers which would be difficult especially the lead dev. And finally, we have a lot of stuff tied to wordpress - all of it would need to be regression tested. Kind of a steep climb IMO.